# Does a peer-to-peer node need to bind and connect over different ports?

Tags: tcp

The key difference between Client-Server and Peer-to-Peer network is that in peer-to-peer each node can act as both server and client. Do the nodes provide services, `bind()`, over a different port than they request for the services, `connect()`?

Answer (score 0):

TCP or UDP ports are defined in either layer 4 of the OSI model or layer 3 of the TCP/IP model, both are defined as the 'transport' layer. OSI layer 5 'session layer' uses the ports defined in layer 4 to create sockets and sessions between communicating devices/programs/etc. In a peer-to-peer application, the natural thing to do is to use a single port for both outgoing and incoming connections. While this model is supported by the TCP protocol, it is not supported by the sockets API — if a socket is listening on port p, then binding an active socket to port p will fail. This is a limitation of the sockets API, not the 'transport' layer, and one that impairs the writing of peer-to-peer applications based on TCP.

Comment: The socket API limitation was lifted by [setting the `SO_REUSEPORT` flag](https://lwn.net/Articles/542629/) on both the server and the client sockets, which can then bind to the same port. One of the client connection attempts will fail (where the peer's server socket accepted the connection), and you'll end up with a single connection.